# after multiple delete maintain order column

Tags: php, mysql, database

in my project i have to maintain a order of every record and if i delete in between i have to maintain order in a form that order don't have any gape like after 3 next is 4 only... not 5 or 6......my display like.

[image]

if i delete multiple record that have Rule ID are 1,3 and 4...then my rule ID 0 remain 0, 2 becomes 1, and 5 becomes 3...like that i want. i am deleting record base on id.

```
id    rileid
1     0
3     1
5     2
6     3
11    4
14    5
```

how to do that? please help me.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: 1. Before delete a record, get its order.
2. Select all records that have order greater than the order of the deleted record, sort them in ascending order.
3. Loop over these records, so for each record update its order by subtracting 1 (new order = old order - 1)